# How to disable laptop sound while streaming(screen sharing) via webRTC?

Tags: javascript, windows, web, webrtc, screensharing

I have a application which streams the video and audio from a latop to a windows device in a meeting room.
The issue is that the audio is playing from both devices while sharing.

In the app which shares the screen, I have set the video tag property to muted in the local web page as suggested by some sources but the audio still plays from both devices.
<video muted="true" ... >

One work around I used for desktop computers is turning off the master volume while sharing the screen. This stop the audio in the desktop, but streams properly to the reciever device. But this does not work for laptops as muting master audio stops the streaming audio as well.

Any help appreciated.